# SSH asking for password at login and not passphrase

Tags: ssh, passwords, key, passphrase

I recently used this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04 
When I created the public key I opted to use a passphrase. When I connect via ssh from my local machine it is only asking me for a "password" (as it normally would). I assumed that it would now ask for a "passphrase" and "password". Am I correct in assuming this? If so, then I must have done something wrong, as it only ask's for a "password" and from there it all works as normal.

Ok, to give some more info, this is what I did. Created the key on my local machine, saved it in/as   home/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa . I now have 2 files at that location id_rsa and id_rsa.pub . I copied the key from id_rsa.pub and On the server I added the key to .ssh/authorized_keys . Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing your key to the client? SSH by default should pick up the key if it is located `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

If you chose a different name when generating the key, you need to specify this with the identity `-i` flag.

```
ssh -i ~/path/to/key -p 22 user@device
```

If you are still getting a prompt for a password, you server must be configured incorrectly. If this is the case, please edit your question to include relevant details, and I will edit my answer were applicable.

Comment: I believe I did it the way you are saying. I edited my question to show what I did, where the files are stored, and what they are named. Thank you for your help

Comment: Reading your edit, please be sure that the contents of `authorized_keys` contains your `_pub` key, not the encryption key!

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. I went back to double check after reading your comment. I did copy the key from id_rsa.pub, but apparently the whole key did not copy when I copy/pasted it in. Only a part of the key was there. I replaced it, logged out, logged back in and it seems to be right now.

Comment: Did you use `vi` to paste? Make sure you `i` to insert before pasting. Cheers dude, glad its working. Be sure to upboat and accept for visibiltiy :D